# How to add username and password in sqllocaldb

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-localdb

I am going to start work on new Desktop application. There is I want to use light weight and standalone database so that I am going use SQL LocalDB but I want to add authentication. There I need username and password before accessing database but authentication not applied there please help me how can I do it.

If we cannot add username add password in SQL LocalDB then please suggest me any another database that will best for me and also I can use entity framework with that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22):

To add your new DB user to your `MSSQLLocalDB` you need to connect to it and execute this:

```
CREATE LOGIN your_user WITH PASSWORD = 'your_password';
CREATE USER your_user FOR LOGIN your_user;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'your_user'
```

Then you will be able to connect to `MSSQLLocalDB` database engine with `SQL Server Authentication` using these credentials.

```
Server name: (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
User: your_user
Password: your_password
```

Or you can use instance pipe name instead of `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` as a `Server name` (see below where to get it).

**Initial connection to your local DB from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**

Initially to run the SQL command above you need to connect to your `MSSQLLocalDB` with `Windows Authentication`. You can do it in two ways (try the second if the first one won't work by default).

**Using instance name**

```
Server name: (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

**Using instance pipe name**

From the command line go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\` (you might need to use other versions and replace `\130\` with your folder name) and run `SqlLocalDB.exe` to find the local DB instances you have:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe i
```

Make sure you have `MSSQLLocalDB` listed. Then run this command to see the `MSSQLLocalDB` status (the first line) and start if it's stopped (the second line):

```
SqlLocalDB.exe i MSSQLLocalDB
SqlLocalDB.exe start MSSQLLocalDB
```

Then you can execute `SqlLocalDB.exe i MSSQLLocalDB` again to see the the instance pipe name. Something like this `np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#D7900618\tsql\query`

To connect in `SSMS` you need to enter:

```
Server name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#D7900618\tsql\query
Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

Answer (score 1):

just want to add you need sysadmin role so you can create databases

using this code

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER your_user;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost, Authentication=Windows Authentication, Database= employeedetails");
     con.Open();
```

if you want sql server authentication than read this :
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162132.aspx

Comment: but I want sql server authentication